# Solving an equation for an unknown matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have come across the following equation but not sure how to solve it for matrix $D$. Let matrices $E$, $M$ and $D$ are three symmetric, $2\times 2$ and semi p.d. matrices. How to solve the equation $M = ED + DE$ for D, where $M$ and $E$ are known?

I tried the following,
\begin{equation}
M = ED + DE = E^{1/2}DE^{1/2}+E^{1/2}DE^{1/2} = E^{1/2}(D+D) E^{1/2}
\end{equation}
Then, we get $D = \frac{1}{2}E^{-1/2}ME^{-1/2}$. But I do not think it is correct as I found a counterexample, and also it shows $ED=DE$ which is not always true.

I appreciate any help in this regard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called a [sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation), and there are many known ways to solve it (for instance, on the linked wikipedia article). Naively, the idea is to write $X$ as a vector rather than a matrix, and encode all the relevant linear conditions in one (bigger) matrix.

You can also find information at [this](https://nhigham.com/2020/09/01/what-is-the-sylvester-equation/) wonderful blog post. Though now that you know the name, I'm confident you'll have no issues finding solution techniques!

---

I hope this helps ^_^